# RAD Studio stopped working

Tags: delphi, windows-10, delphi-xe8

Periodically as I work on XE8 under Windows 10 64 bit the user interface will stop working and through up the dialog "Embarcadero RAD Studio for Windows has stopped working". This requires a restart with loss of editing to that point.

It doesn't seem to be associated with any one task I am performing except that I have a rather large project loaded and am looking at the source code with the editor.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Yeah, it's buggy. The latest version is better. Apparently.

Comment: *I have a rather large project loaded*

aka "out-of-memory" aka "internal error".

Forbidden answer: you could "hack" Delphi and enable Large Address Aware plus increase size of stack. This will increase a little bit time which could use Delphi without crashes.